# Custom Api Providers

Tags: angularjs

I am creating api provider for my app by following [this gitcode](https://gist.github.com/jelbourn/6276338) and [google ng-conf](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg&t=25m5s). But this is overriding $routeProvider in my app. As when I check for $routeProvider in the console(in app config) it gives me the instance of my apiProvider only. Why is this happening? How $routeProvider and apiProvider can be used simultaneously? Please refer [this gitcode](https://gist.github.com/jelbourn/6276338) and the code below..

```
websiteApp.provider('customApi',
  function() {

var baseRoute = '';
this.endpoints = {};

this.setBaseRoute = function(route) {
  this.baseRoute = route;
};

this.endpoint = function(name) {

  var endpointConfig = new ApiEndpointConfig();
  this.endpoints[name] = endpointConfig;
  return endpointConfig;
};

this.$get = ['$injector', function($injector) {
  console.log("$get");
  var api = {};
  var self = this;

  angular.forEach(this.endpoints,
    function(endpointConfig, name) {
      api[name] = $injector.instantiate(ApiEndpoint, {
        baseRoute: self.baseRoute,
        endpointConfig: endpointConfig
      });
    });
  return api;
}];
});

websiteApp.config(['FacebookProvider', 'customApiProvider', '$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, customApiProvider, FacebookProvider) {

customApiProvider.setBaseRoute('/api/v0/');

$routeProvider
.when('/search',
  {
    templateUrl: 'assets/angular/widgets/partials/search.html'
 })
.when('/',
  {
    templateUrl: 'assets/angular/widgets/partials/recommendations.html'
  });

var myAppId = APPID;
FacebookProvider.setAppId('myAppId');
FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);
}]);
```

Comment: Why if you want both to run both simultaneously you want to create a second one?

Comment: I didn't get you properly. I think you are asking why I need both of them simultaneously. The reason for that is: apiProvider is there to make the code look clean and manageable for the apis. While I need a $routeProvider for routing the templates. Apart from that I need a FacebookProvider which is required by a third party app I am using along. But both FacebookProvider and $routeProvider are getting overwritten by the apiProvider.

Comment: Why services or factories didn't help you? Why you think you need to reinvent a service?

Comment: I will use the services. But all this is required to cutout the boilerplate in the code. This is the inspiration https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: more specifically http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg&t=25m5s

Comment: Have updated the code in the question. Please refer.

Comment: Your parameter order must match the string order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing minified safe code instead of using ngmin the parameters order must match the string order.